# How to convert equation from long to Biginteger

Tags: java, biginteger

So I am doing this problem which requires to calculate the equations. At first i thought `long` would be enough for the range but now it has exceeded the `long` range and now i have to use `BigInteger`. I have to convert one equation but I haven't been able to

This is the equation :

```
count =(n2/n3)-((n1-1)/n3);
```

Count can be `long` but `n1`,`n2`,`n3` should be `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simplifies to:

```
-(n1-n2-1)/n3
```

and in Java

```
BigInteger count = n1
  .subtract(n2)
  .subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1))
  .negate()
  .divide(n3)
```

Comment: Note that I assume {n1, n2, n3} are BigInteger's.

Comment: are you sure `-(n1-n2-1)/n3` is correct? where is first `/n3`? i've tried to simplify but that division gave me problems.... also to fit OP just make count long and add a .longValue() at the end ;)

Comment: Yes, I have an engineering degree. If you want step by step solution http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28n2%2Fn3%29-%28%28n1-1%29%2Fn3%29. Same as (-n1+n2+1)/n3 as well.

Comment: now I see it!!! Sweeet @Margus .... really appreciatte!! :) also a great resource :)

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion !!!  we have to take range as n1 and n2 .. and n3 would be multiples. For example  if we take n1 as 1 and n2 as 10 .. and n3 as 2 which is a multiple .. it leads to the final answer of 5 which also obtaining by your suggestion. Thanks very much!!  Thanks for the link too !!! Much appreciate it ..

Answer (score 3):

BigInteger seems to have a longValue() method that should be able to do the job:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

```
long count = (n2
                .divide(n3))
                .substract( (n1
                .subtract(BigInteger.ONE))
                .divide(n3)
             ).longValue()
```

Answer (score 2):

This *oneliner* should do the trick...

```
long count;
BigInteger n1, n2, n3;
n1 = n2 = n3 = new BigInteger("1231232");

//count =(n2/n3)-((n1-1)/n3);

//count = (n2/n3)
count   = (n2.divide(n3))
        // - 
        .subtract(
            //((n1-1)/n3);
            ((n1.subtract(new BigInteger("1").divide(n3))))
        ).longValue();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works . This is the first time i am using Biginteger. Thanks for the clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BigInteger#valueOf(long val)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#valueOf%28long%29)

```
    count = (BigInteger.valueOf(n2.intValue()).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(n3.intValue()))).
 subtract(((BigInteger.valueOf(n1.intValue()).
subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(n1.intValue()))).
divide(BigInteger.valueOf(n3.intValue())));
```

Comment: Sry typo again. I need my coffee ;)